# Enabling command hashing in tcsh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tcsh, audit

It seems command hashing is disabled by default in our tcsh environment, and I'm not permitted to get it enabled across the board. Instead I'm looking to enable command hashing within individual scripts, all of which contain while loops, so I'd expect the first iteration to loop through all the paths defined in $PATH and subsequent iterations to hit the exact path from the internal hash table. The purpose is to reduce the number of failed execve calls captured by the audit service.

First question, is there a command similar to "hash" in tcsh to output the internal hash table? Hashstat doesn't appear to work, it doesn't output anything on the prompt, perhaps because hashing is disabled? When I did get it to print something, it printed only the number and size of hash buckets, not any specific commands.

Main question, I've tried adding "rehash" to the beginning of the script, which has helped reduce the number of execve calls per command from ~5 to ~2 (even on the first iteration). For some reason, it still always tries to run commands from "/sbin" first. Any suggestions on what to check to see why after running rehash it still tries to execute a command from an invalid path, or is there an alternative way to enable command hashing from within a script?

Side question, bash on the other hand still manages to hit the correct path even with the hash table disabled. Any idea how it does this without command hashing?

Lastly, strace hasn't captured the failed execve calls captured by audit. I've tried simple `strace sleep`, and `strace -f -e trace=execve sleep`, both essentially just showing the correct entry, but not the failed ones:

`execve("/bin/sleep", ["sleep"], 0x7ffe0d773ff8 /* 32 vars */) = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite a complicated issue, but I'll try to explain

## How are the commands being hashed in `tcsh`

Command hashing in `tcsh` is quite different than in `bash`. In `bash`, every time is command is executed for the first time, it searches for its location in the `PATH` environment variable and caches it. The next time the same command is being executed, it will use the full path already hashed.

Here's the relevant section from the `tcsh` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh):

> `rehash`
>
> Causes the internal hash table of the contents of the directories in
> the `path` variable to be recomputed. This is needed if new commands
> are added to directories in `path` while you are logged in. This
> should be necessary only if you add commands to one of your own
> directories, or if a systems programmer changes the contents of one of
> the system directories. Also flushes the cache of home directories
> built by tilde expansion.

> `path`
>
> A list of directories in which to look for executable commands. [...]
> A shell which is given neither the `-c` nor the `-t` option **hashes the
> contents of the directories in path after reading `~/.tcshrc` and each
> time `path` is reset**. If one adds a new command to a directory in
> `path` while the shell is active, one may need to do a `rehash` for the shell to find it.

In other words `tcsh` performs the hashing for all the commands found in the directories in the `path` variable, only when:

1. The shell is started.
2. The `path` is being modified.
3. You manually run the `rehash` command.

So after you start the shell it will hash all the commands found in `path`, and further commands will not be hashed unless you modify the `path` or run `rehash`.

## What is the reason your hashing might be disabled?

The man pages specific exactly the conditions for this to happen:

> This hashing mechanism is not used:
>
> 1. If hashing is turned explicitly off via `unhash`.
> 2. If the shell was given a `-f` argument.

Here's an example. If I start the shell with the `-f` flag, `hashstat` will be empty because the hashing is disabled.

```
$ tcsh -f
> hashstat
```

The same would happen if somewhere you run the `unhash` command.

However, in both scenarios, you can still enable it by running `rehash.

```
> rehash
> hashstat
512 hash buckets of 8 bits each
```

## Why does `tcsh` executes some commands in different paths even if hashing is enabled?

### Understanding `hashstat`

Let's look at the output of `hashstat`:

```
$ hashstat
512 hash buckets of 8 bits each
```

It says there are 512 hash buckets. `tcsh` uses a hashing function to calculate the hash id of each command, and in this case the value would be between 0 and 511. This means that some commands might (and probably will) have the same hash. The initial number of buckets and bits might be differ depending on the number of directories in your `PATH`.

So let's say two command A and B have the same hash (let's say the hash of both commands is 123). Let's say command A is located `/bin`, and command B is located `/usr/bin`. What happens then?

It means that in the bucket of hash id 123, there will be two paths: Both `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. And when you execute  either A or B, it will try to `exec` those commands in both of those directories (in their order in `PATH`) until it succeeds. You'll see an example further down this answer. But for now let's talk about `rehash`.

### `rehash` "secret" parameters

The `rehash` builtin in `tcsh` has some "secret" undocumented optional arguments that you can only see in the source code. The options are:

```
rehash [hashlength [hashwidth [debug]]]
```

For instance, you can change the number of hash buckets the following way:

```
$ hashstat
512 hash buckets of 8 bits each   # At the beginning, 512 buckets

$ rehash 4096                     # increasing the bucket number

$ hashstat
4096 hash buckets of 8 bits each  # Now there are 4096 buckets instead of 512
```

I won't talk about the hash width, because it only has effect if the length is set to 0 (and then the width would be used internally to calculate the length of the hash). Besides for that that it has no meaning.

#### Important note

Increasing the table length could help you minimize the possible number of conflicts between different commands. So if you're doing some tests you can try that and see if there is some improvement.

Anyway, the **really** interesting part is yet to come.

### Showing the internal hashing table

You could increase the debugging for hash operations by setting the last argument to 1 or 3. Let's see how it works.

```
$ rehash 0 0 3 
hash=19   dir=0  prog=addgnupghome
hash=0    dir=0  prog=addpart
hash=206  dir=0  prog=agetty
hash=498  dir=0  prog=alternatives
hash=463  dir=0  prog=applygnupgdefaults
hash=323  dir=0  prog=blkdiscard
hash=342  dir=0  prog=blkid
hash=277  dir=0  prog=blkzone
hash=410  dir=0  prog=blockdev
hash=500  dir=0  prog=cfdisk
[...]
```

It shows you exactly all the commands are hashed and where.

For instance, the command `addgnupghome` has a hash value of 19, and it was found in directory number 0. What is directory number 0?

Those directories are numbered according to their order in your `PATH` environment variables (which is linked to the `path` shell variable in `tcsh`).

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

The directories in my `PATH` are numbered the following way:

0. `/usr/sbin`
1. `/usr/bin`
2. `/sbin`
3. `/bin`

So if command `addgnupghome` was found in directory number 0, it means it's located in `/usr/sbin`.

### Examples

Let's save the output of our rehash command (after I've set the debug to 3) to a file:

```
$ rehash > rehash.log
```

Now, let's look at a certain hash:

```
$ grep hash=498 rehash.log
hash=498  dir=0  prog=alternatives
hash=498  dir=1  prog=passwd
```

There are two commands that are mapped to the same hash (498):

- `alternatives`

  - found in **dir 0** (`/usr/sbin`)
- `passwd`

  - found in **dir 1** (`/usr/bin`).

Another nice effect of increasing the debug level is in the `where` builtin (*"Reports all known instances of command, including aliases, builtins and executables in `path`"*). Usually it just shows the found location of the executables, but with the increased debugs it also shows you missed location, and you will see

```
$ where alternatives
/usr/sbin/alternatives
hash miss: /usr/bin/alternatives

$ where passwd
hash miss: /usr/sbin/passwd
/usr/bin/passwd
```

You could see it will search for both commands in both directories: `/usr/sbin` and `/usr/bin`!

### Confirming with `strace`.

You wrote:

> Lastly, `strace` hasn't captured the failed `execve` calls captured by
> audit. I've tried simple `strace sleep`, and `strace -f -e trace=execve sleep`, both essentially just showing the correct entry,
> but not the failed ones:
>
> ```
> execve("/bin/sleep", ["sleep"], 0x7ffe0d773ff8 /* 32 vars */) = 0
> ```

If you run `strace sleep`, it's no longer the shell that searches for the location of `sleep` - it's the `strace` command. The shell only searches for the location of the command that you actually run, which is the first word in your line (in this case, `strace`). The rest of the words are considered parameters that are just passed to the command. So before `strace` executes the `sleep` command, `strace` itself searches for the command in the directories in your `PATH`.

If you want to actually see how your shell finds the location of your commands, you'll need to attach `strace` to your shell (from another terminal) and then run the command.

For instance, I have a `tcsh` process running with pid 21033. From another terminal, I attach `strace` to this pid.

```
$ strace -f -qq -e trace=execve -p 21033
```

If I run `alternatives` on the attached shell, it will immediately find it in the first directory in the list of this hash.

```
[pid 19134] execve("/usr/sbin/alternatives", ["alternatives", "--help"], [/* 125 vars */]) = 0
```

But `passwd` command is located in the second directory, and will fail the `execve` in the first one:

```
[pid 20919] execve("/usr/sbin/passwd", ["passwd", "-h"], [/* 125 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 20919] execve("/usr/bin/passwd", ["passwd", "-h"], [/* 125 vars */]) = 0
```

Here's the opposite example, of a hash that's mapped only to one command:

```
$ grep hash=102 rehash.log
hash=102  dir=1  prog=curl   # Only curl has hash 102

$ where curl
/usr/bin/curl                # And indeed "where" only tries one dir
```

## Disclaimer

Everything I wrote here was based on what I saw in the `tcsh` [source code](https://github.com/tcsh-org/tcsh/) and by testing in my own environment (I have version 6.20.00). This might be different according to the version and the way the `tcsh` was compiled on your distro.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed and thorough answer and for taking the trouble to go through the source code! 

I've tested rehash 4096 on 2 servers both running tcsh version 6.18 and it worked a treat.

Thanks again, much appreciated!

Comment: @Maikol in my work people also work with `tcsh`, and once you pointed out those issues and I tested it myself, I've found some weird discrepancies (like different commands were failing on different paths, they didn't try the same paths, but some succeeded on the first time for directory that's lower in the order of `PATH`) and it got me into this rabbit hole... I just couldn't stop before I understood it completely. Very gratifying, though it's pretty esoteric and for most purposes almost meaningless.